# URL Rewrite with spaces or with -?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting, canonical-url, negative-seo

Which URL is more SEO?

`mydomain.com/category-name/article-name.html`

OR

`mydomain.com/category name/article name.html`

I have read some articles about URL Rewriting but there I can't find any conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace spaces with hyphens in URL's without a doubt.

They are more readable otherwise URL's will be encoded in the browser like:-

```
example.com/category%20name/article%20name.html
```

It's more friendly for search engines and humans like:-

```
example.com/category-name/article-name.html
```

You can accomplish replacing spaces with hyphens by using the php function `str_replace` like so:-

```
str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
```

It would be best practice to implement this in the files that generate the URL's with the above php function rather than to hash a series or `RewriteCond`'s and `RewriteRule`'s in `.htaccess` to replace spaces with hyphens just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about SEO - using spaces (or other unsafe characters) in a URL is bad practise full stop.  The original reason given for this was....

```
 Characters can be unsafe for a number of reasons.  The space
   character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and
   insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or
   typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.
```

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Although most browsers will now parse them fine, unsafe characters should never really be used in any filename at all.  You can't guarantee that a server will encode them correctly and there is no benefit over a hyphen.